# Overwrite one css rule with another?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

A question about CSS.

I am working on some dated code. This code has its own css rules which are linked to some 'css manager'... now I want to use `jQuery UI` with its nice and cute dialogues etc.

Now my question is: 
I have a css rule say...

> #menu-bar{something}

jQuery UI is using rules like:

> .ui-dialog-titlebar{something2}

Can I (without modifying jQueryUI stylesheets) do something akin to :

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar = #menu-bar?
```

So .ui-dialog-titlebar will be overwritten with {something} from #menu-bar?

Thanks in advance.

PS. Let me add that I can not simply do

> `.ui-dialog-titlebar {something}`

becasue {something} is changing depending on the 'style manager' used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a css rule can *inherit* from another one, definitely not CSS 2 or CSS 3. What you can do is to add multiple css classes to the elements. In your case, you could simply add the ID to the dialog element:

```
<div id="menu-bar" title="dialog">...</div>
```

or add it programmically:

```
$('.dialog').dialog(...).attr('id', 'menu-bar');
```

Note though, `#menu-bar` should really be a class rather than an ID, if you want multiple elements to have the style.